# Recursively grep results and pipe back

Tags: grep

I need to find some matching conditions from a file and recursively find the next conditions in previously matched files , i have something like this

input.txt

123

22

33

The files where you need to find above terms in following files, the challenge is if 123 is found in say 10 files , the 22 should be searched in these 10 files only and so on...
Example of files are like f1,f2,f3,f4.....f1200

so it is like i need to grep -w "123" f* | grep -w "123" | .....

its not possible to list them manually so any easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using awk script, i ve encountered a similar problem and this will work fine

```
awk '{ if(!NR){printf("grep -w %d f*|",$1)} else {printf("grep -w %d f*",$1)} }' input.txt | sh
```

What it Does?

- it reads input.txt line by line
- until it is at last record , it prints grep -w %d | (note there is a
  pipe here)
- which is then sent to shell for execution and results are piped back
  to back
- and when you reach the end the pipe is avoided

Comment: Does that reduce the files it has to scan at every iteration though?

Comment: yes it does its same as grep -w "123" f* | grep -w "22" | grep -w "33"

Comment: Ah yes, I should have reasoned that myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps taking a meta-programming viewpoint would help.  Have `grep` output a series of `grep` commands.  Or write a little PERL program.  Maybe Ruby, if the mood suits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -lw` to write the list of file names that matched (note that it will stop after finding the first match).

You capture the list of file names and use that for the next iteration in a loop.